# Is the playlistItems date wrong

Tags: youtube-api

Given the uploads playlist of a channel I can query the playlist using `playlistItems.list`. Querying for snippet gives us publishedAt.  However the publishedAt date does not match up with querying each video individually or the time on the web client. The time given by querying the video itself matches up with the time given by the website. Also the returned videos are ordered by this date however this is not the order given on the actual channel.

What does this time represent and is it possible to get the uploads playlist ordered by (actual) publish date?

Comment: Maybe some concrete examples might help?

Comment: On this upload playlist for user arumba07 with playlistId UUISPcad-6svNxgViVr_syvA  we see ATdv7WNZkRI is published at 2015-08-14T22:12:20.000Z. However it wasn't published until Saturday evening and looking at the video list we see publishedAt is set to 2015-08-15T16:00:00.000Z which is the time it was actually published on

Answer (score 3):

From the [playlistItems documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.publishedAt):

> **snippet.publishedAt**
>
> `datetime` The date and time that the item was **added
>   to the playlist**. The value is specified in ISO 8601
>   (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

This differs from the `publishedAt` value for `videos.list`, which gives you the **actual date** it was published. If you wanted the videos in the actual order they were uploaded, you'd have to get the ID of each video in the uploads playlist, then the videos.list `publishedAt` value for each one, then put them in order.

Comment: It's a bit unusual that the videos in the uploads playlist weren't added in the same order they were published. That might be a bug. If you want, you can file a ticket [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).